# Link external object to a Google Sheets spreadsheet

Tags: externalobjects

I need to link an external object to a Google Sheets spreadsheet with the intention of having real-time updates. Does anyone know if this is possible and the best way to do it without using Cross-Org, as the cost is extremely high? I've done some research, and I've come across suggestions such as OData, consuming the Google Sheets API, and Files Connect.

Sincerely,

Answer (score 0):

Are records of that object exposed in Salesforce to be accessed via API?
If so, you can simply pull the records using a Google connector like [G-Connector](https://www.xappex.com/knowledge-base/installing-g-connector/).